# Putting fetch function in a separate component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to take out the **fetchImages** function from the following component and put it inside a new component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import UnsplashImage from './UnsplashImage';

const Collage = () => {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [loaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

  const fetchImages = (count = 10) => {
    const apiRoot = 'https://api.unsplash.com';
    const accessKey =
      '<API KEY>';

    axios
      .get(`${apiRoot}/photos/random?client_id=${accessKey}&count=${count}`)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        setImages([...images, ...res.data]);
        setIsLoaded(true);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchImages();
  }, []);

  return (
            <div className="image-grid">
              {loaded
                ? images.map(image => (
                    <UnsplashImage
                      url={image.urls.regular}
                      key={image.id}
                      alt={image.description}
                    />
                  ))
                : ''}
            </div>
  );
};

export default Collage;
```

For this, I created a new component called **api.js**, removed the entire **fetchImage** function from the above component and put it in to **api.js** like this:

**api.js**

```
    const fetchImages = (count = 10) => {
        const apiRoot = 'https://api.unsplash.com';
        const accessKey =
          '<API KEY>';

        axios
          .get(`${apiRoot}/photos/random?client_id=${accessKey}&count=${count}`)
          .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            setImages([...images, ...res.data]);
            setIsLoaded(true);
          });
      };

export default fetchImages;
```

Next I took **setIsLoaded(true);** from **api.js** and paste it inside Collage component like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchImages();
    setIsLoaded(true);
  }, []);
```

Now I can import **fetchImages** in to Collage component.

However, I don't know what should I do with this line inside the fetchImages function? This needs to go to Collage component, but **res.data** is not defined inside Collage component.

```
setImages([...images, ...res.data]);
```

How should I handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is many way to do that, but in your case.
You should use

```
 const fetchImages = (afterComplete, count = 10) => {
  const apiRoot = 'https://api.unsplash.com';
  const accessKey = '<API KEY>';

  axios
    .get(`${apiRoot}/photos/random?client_id=${accessKey}&count=${count}`)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      afterComplete(res.data);
    });
};

export default fetchImages;
```

And in your Collage component:

```
const afterComplete = (resData) =>{
  setImages([...images, ...resData]);
  setIsLoaded(true);
}

useEffect(() => {
  fetchImages(afterComplete);
}, []);
```

Comment: How you got the axios instnce available here ? and is it afterComplete is function here ? .. I Tried similar but unable to access afterComplete  function...

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is create a custom hook ( sort of like a HOC)... Since I don't have an unsplash API key I'll give you an example with a different API but the idea is the same:

Here is your custom hook:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const useFetch = url => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const fetchUser = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    const [user] = data.results;
    setData(user);
    setLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUser();
  }, []);

  return { data, loading };
};
```

Here is how you can use it in your component:

```
import { useFetch } from './api';

const App = () => {
  const { data, loading } = useFetch('https://api.randomuser.me/');

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {loading ? (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      ) : (
        <>
          <div className="name">
            {data.name.first} {data.name.last}
          </div>
          <img className="cropper" src={data.picture.large} alt="avatar" />
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is a live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/3ymnlq59xm

Comment: That's a nice hook, but it has nothing to do with [Higher-Order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html).